# SQL cross match data from different columns and rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been having hard times figuring out how to select the following...

I have two tables

```
Table_users                      Table_followers
| id | name     |                | follow_id | user_id |
| 1  | John     |                | 1         | 2       |
| 2  | Max      |                | 3         | 1       |
| 3  | Mary     |                | 2         | 1       |
| 4  | Robert   |                | 6         | 1       |
| 5  | Robin    |                | 1         | 5       |
| 6  | Sarah    |                | 1         | 6       |
```

1. I'd like to return in a single query users who are following John and John is following them back, so that would be called MATCH.
2. Then users who are following John, FOLLOWERS
3. And finally users followed by John, FOLLOWING

I've used the following query, but it returns duplicates and it's far from what I'm looking for

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, f.follower_id, f.user_id
FROM table_users u
LEFT JOIN table_followers f ON f.follower_id = u.id OR f.user_id = u.id
WHERE (f.user_id != 1 OR f.follower_id != 1) AND u.id != 1
ORDER BY u.id ASC";
```

Desired result would be like...

```
| uid | name     | match | follower | following |
| 2   | Max      | 1     | null     | null      |
| 6   | Sarah    | 1     | null     | null      |
| 3   | Mary     | null  | 1        | null      |
| 5   | Robin    | null  | null     | 1         |
```

Would it be possible at all with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to join the follower table twice (once for followers, once for following) and do a query like this:

```
select 
    u.id,
    u.name, 
    case when follow_id and user_id then 1 end as `match`,
    case when follow_id and user_id is null then 1 end as follower,
    case when user_id and follow_id is null then 1 end as following
from Table_users u
left join (select user_id from Table_followers where follow_id = 1) followers 
    on u.id = followers.user_id
left join (select follow_id from Table_followers where user_id = 1) following 
    on u.id = following.follow_id
where u.id <> 1 and (follow_id or user_id)
order by `match` desc, follower desc, following desc, u.id;
```

I'm sure there are more efficient and cleaner ways to do this, but it's late and the old brain is only working at half speed ;)

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8818ec/20)

With MySQL the select part can be further reduced to this:

```
select 
    u.id,
    u.name, 
    ifnull((follow_id and user_id),0) as `match`,
    (follow_id and user_id is null) as follower,
    (user_id and follow_id is null) as following
from Table_users u
```

But this would give you 0 instead of null for the missing values. ([Sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8818ec/26)).

Comment: @Armand Then the last sample link should be what you want. :)